# How to set an startup command for PowerShell in Windows Terminal app for specific pane?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, terminal

I set Terminal Windows application to be in startup of Windows.

I have the following panes in Terminal in the following order:

1. Ubuntu
2. PowerShell
3. PowerShell
4. CMD
5. Ubuntu

Now I want to whenever I open the Terminal app, the pane number 2 runs this command:

```
ssh -qD1111 myserver
```

Is that possible to do so? If yes, how? Or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the settings (`ctrl + ,`) and select your profile then you can use the 'Command line' to setting to tell PowerShell to run ssh when it starts:

For Pwsh:

```
"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -command "&{ ssh -qD1111 myserver }"
```

For PowerShell:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command "&{ ssh -qD1111 myserver }"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, I don't want every time I open powershell it runs that command. I want a specific tab do that

Comment: Can you create a new tab and then use the above commands?